# Best Practices for preloading initialState in redux app from server without rendering?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is this even possible? the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924429/what-are-your-best-practices-for-preloading-initialstate-in-your-redux-apps) has answers that allude to the server rendering as explained in the [docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/server-rendering).

But if we wanted to make that same counter example, but our `App` included libraries that don't support server rendering (the `window is not an object` sadness), how can we pass initial state from query string?

Comment: I think you can avoid re-rendering if your do not subscribe to the store.

Comment: You can store your saved serialized state into a global variable and assign get it when initializing redux.
If your backend does not serve directly react you can make an HTTP request to your server before bootstrapping React app

Comment: I need to be able to pass query params to client as initial state but I do not need to do any other rendering server side. `foo.com/?form=23&user=11`

Comment: You can access the query string with JavaScript and dispatch and action to store that data. Do not subscribe to that reducer to avoid re-rendering.

Comment: not sure I understand what you are saying. store the data where? i need to pass that data back to client with initial page load.